# Retrieve related entity with entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there a method in Entity Framework that allows us to know if two entities are related or not?

Comment: You could loop the entities properties and check them against with the `is` functionality. E.G. `if (property is relatedEntityType)` Although I assume you're the architect of the system so should know which entities will be related. Could you go in to more information for us by any chance?

Comment: This question could really be taken in multiple ways.  two that come to mind are:  (a) Given an author entity *object* and a book entity *object*, how do I tell if this is one of the authors for this book, or perhaps a more complicated question.  Or (b) given an entity *type* and another entity *type*, how do I tell if they are in the same model?  Or directly related?  something like that.  I guessed one way below, others might guess the other way.  Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: We should know the related entities before persist them on the database, because the object instantiation depending that which exists on XML file (A dynamic object instantiation )

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your variables are all attached to the same context.  You want to know if your `bar1` variable is one of the bar values in the `foo.bars` collection.  You could just do:

```
theyAreEqual = foo.bars.Contains(bar1);
```

If your entity variables are not attached to the context, then you might have different variables that logically refer to the same db records, but are actually pointers to *different* objects.  So, you'd need to compare the key values:

```
theyAreLogicallyEqual = foo.bars.Select(b => b.BarId).Contains(bar1.BarId);
```

I assume you know about this, but for others reading this answer, [the differences in value and reference type equality](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/03/31/12/) is important here.

Comment: I just commented the previous please take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to Entities. You can match every object in entity1 and check if there is a corresponding data/object entity in entity2.

```
using (NorthwindEntities nw = new NorthwindEntities())    
{    
       var cusotmers = from c in nw.Customers    
                       where c.City == "London"    
                       select c;    
}
```

You can find more info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc161164.aspx

Comment: The application is fully customizable based on XML file, so we can have an embedded web forms with different object; just after object instantiation we would like two know what's the related entities.